# Not able to call python function from robotframework

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a Python class file `Myclass.py`

```
class Myclass(object):
    def __init__(self,age,marks,city):
        self.age=age
        self.marks=marks
        self.city=city


    def sample_func(self ,arg1):
        self.arg1=arg1
        return self.age,self.marks,self.city
```

My sample.robot file is:

```
*** Settings ***
Library      Myclass.py    ${age}    ${marks}    ${city}

*** Variables ***
${arg1}    pankaj
${arg2}    Mishra
${age}    35
${marks}    26
${city}    noida

*** Test Cases ***
Test
    Test_MakeMyClass    ${arg1}    ${arg2}

*** Keywords ***
Test_MakeMyClass
    [Arguments]    ${arg1}    ${arg2}
    #Below command is working
    #${result} =    Myclass.sample_func    ${arg1}

    #$This one is throwing error 
    ${result} =     Call Method     Myclass.sample_func    ${arg1}    ${arg2}
   [Return]       ${result}
```

However, when I run the robot file, it gives the error:

```
Object 'sample_func' does not have method 'pankaj'
```

what wrong am I doing here?

Comment: Why are you creating a keyword that makes a new instance of the library? That's not how robot libraries work.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley , i  have edited my code now..not able to understand what is the problem now

Comment: The above code does not give the error `Object 'sample_func' does not have method 'pankaj' like you claim it does. Please make sure that the code you post is the actual code that gives the error you say it does.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley..i was able to get the result pass with command       
  ${result} =    Myclass.sample_func    ${arg1}   ..i am copy pasting my robot file content here

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `sample_func` only accepts a single argument but you are passing two arguments. The `self` argument is automatically passed by python when the function is called, so your first argument is going to be assigned to `arg1`.

The solution is to either stop calling the keyword with two arguments, or add another argument to `sample_func`. Either of the following will work:

```
# Myclass.py
class Myclass(object):
    ...
    def sample_func(self, arg1):
        ...

# sample.robot
...
sample_func  ${arg1}
```

OR

```
# Myclass.py
class Myclass(object):
    ...
    def sample_func(self, arg1, arg2):
        ...

# sample.robot
...
sample_func  ${arg1}  ${arg2}
```

Answer (score 0):

as error message says:

```
Keyword 'MakeMyClass' expected 2 arguments, got 0.
```

**MakeMyClass** keyword in Test testcase was called without arguments.

Append 2 arguments after MakeMyClass (remember about separators after MakeMyClass and arguments - at least 2 spaces) in Test testcase:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test
    MakeMyClass  something1  someghing2
```

Comment: @jozefow..please see the edits.. i am now getting error Object 'makeMyClass' does not have method '"pankaj"'.

Comment: do you need to return instance of class to Robot or you library is just an arbitrary example? 
* change  def makeMyClass(arg1, arg2): to  def makeMyClass(self,arg1, arg2):
* try to have unique keyword names, in library and in robot suite there is MakeMyClass which is valid but can lead to bugs in real test suites